# How to monitor outgoing http requests per user?

Tags: freebsd, monitoring, http

I'd like to know how to monitor users' outgoing http requests. I've got a FreeBSD 8.1 server, and I would like to get an output like this for http requests:

> source MAC address or IP address → destination IP address.

I don't need any other information, just the source of the request and the destination.

Comment: If you are really looking for the source IP or MAC address, then this is best logged at the router. Do expect extraordinarily large logs: the front page of amazon.com sends 95 separate documents, whitehouse.gov sends 55, and cnn.com over 150.

Comment: `tcpdump src host 10.0.0.1 and dst port 80 or dst port 443`

Comment: Why do you need the MAC address anyways?

Comment: I need MAC address to localize easier the users. And yes, it's quite a big log like msw said.

Comment: Another option is to use iftop if you don´t need to inspect packet-per-packet: `iftop -i yourlan0 -N -P -f "src host ip_src and dst host dst_ip"` = http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iftop&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html

Comment: Thanks for everyone for the ideas. But maybe I describe my problem wrong. So I've got a server (FreeBSD). We use it as a firewall NAT server. And I need the users's inside IP addresses. With Ramesh's solution, I get the IP of the server and the ports of the request. My next question is: can I get the inside IP's of the users?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be to use a transparent HTTP proxy (like `squid`) which logs the requests.

Redirect all outgoing HTTP requests to that server. To get the MAC-Adress either correlate with the DHCP servers lease file or use something like `arpwatch`, if the users assign the IPs themselves.